# NHibernate: How to use "IN" with CreateCriteria?

Tags: nhibernate, criteria

I have a parent-child table relationship: Elements -(1 to n)-> ContentBlocks.  Each ContentBlock row has:  unique Id (Id), ElementId, Version, and then some less relevant fields.  I'm trying to get all Content rows that have the highest Version number (and Id) on them.

I have this line of SQL that gives me what I want:

```
SELECT * FROM ContentBlocks WHERE Id IN 
    (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM ContentBlocks GROUP BY ElementId)
```

(this assumes that the latest version has the highest Id)

However, I can't figure out how to get it from NHibernate.  This is the closest I've gotten:

```
var subquery = DetachedCriteria.For<ContentBlock>()
            .SetProjection( Projections.Max( "Id" ) )
            .SetProjection( Projections.GroupProperty( "ElementId" ) );

var query = session.CreateCriteria<ContentBlock>()
            .Add( Subqueries.PropertyIn( "Id", subquery ) ).List<ContentBlock>();
```

If I execute subquery, I get a list of the unique ElementIds in the table. Instead, I need the list of Ids of the newest ContentBlocks.  If I reverse the order of the SetProjections on the subquery, I just get the max of ElementId.

I also tried this way:

```
        subquery = DetachedCriteria.For<ContentBlock>()
            .SetProjection(
                Projections.ProjectionList()
                    .Add( Projections.Max( "Id" ) )
                    .Add( Projections.GroupProperty( "ElementId" ) )
                );
```

but that gets me a list of arrays with 2 elements in it, Id & ElementId, which the CreateCriteria call can't process.

Is there a way to not include the Grouped Property "ElementId" in the results?  Or specify that I want to return Max(Id) instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Not implemented yet](http://216.121.112.228/browse/NH-1426).